# R710 - DRAC Configuration IPv4

Tags: remote-access, drac, dell-poweredge

*** Resolved by rolling back to DRAC6_FRMW_WIN_R279926.EXE ***

---

Having an issue with a new R710 where I cannot enable IPv4 on the iDRAC card.

I have tried enabling IPv4 and setting static IP, Gateway ect however when saving the settings it fails. This has been done using the Dell Setup Disk & during boot (ctrl+E).

Dell OpenManage Server Administrator has been installed on the box which I can see the DRAC card is enabled (has mac address ect) but in the Remote Access  - Additional Configuration menu I am not able to set IPv4 to enabled. Each time I click apply changes it reverts back to Disabled.

Bios ect are all up to date. Any help would be appreciated.

More Informatin;
Device Type: iDRAC6 Enterprise 
IPMI Version: 2.0 
System GUID: 4a35364f-c0c8-3480-3410-00364c4c4544 
Number of Possible Active Sessions 5 
Number of Current Active Sessions 0 
Enable IPMI Over LAN: No 
SOL Enabled: Yes 
MAC Address: BC-30-5B-E9-CA-CF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by rolling back to DRAC6_FRMW_WIN_R279926.EXE

Answer (score 2):

its a new machine, why don't you contact dell support?

Comment: Yes... also check the cable is plugged in to the IDrac NIC.

Comment: it can share the first NIC - a matter of config

Comment: Got it sorted by rolling back the firmware. Thanks.